# SQL query- probably wrong

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying this query, but didn't work

```
INSERT INTO single_user (location_home.id_location_home ) 
SELECT location_home.id_location_home 
WHERE location_home.location = 'London'
```

Any help?

error:

```
for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE location_home.location = 'London'' at line 3
```

thanks

Comment: What is the error you are getting? It appears that you are missing a FROM in your SELECT portion of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO single_user (location_home.id_location_home ) 
SELECT location_home.id_location_home 
FROM some_table
WHERE location_home.location = 'London'
```

You forgot the FROM clause.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing  a FROM Clause.

Also please show the error in the future so we can better diagnose the problem